# Ubuntu server on macbook: how to configure sleep conditions?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, hardware, macintosh

I have an old MacBook which I set up running ubuntu server for a fun project. Unfortunately, whenever I close the lid, it goes to sleep! I really just want this thing as a server, so this is not ideal behavior. Any ideas on how I can configure it to stay awake (fine with the screen turning off) given that I only have shell access?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open `/etc/systemd/logind.conf` in your text editor as root.

add `HandleLidSwitch=ignore`

restart systemd dameon

`sudo restart systemd-logind`

or

`sudo systemctl restart systemd-logind`